# Template Inheritance for Handlebars

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

I am trying for template inheritance from base.html to other templates using handlebars.But am not getting soul for this.

Please, Can anyone  help me out with simple DEMO. with base.html , extend.html

For example ,
Base.html

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Extend.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}<h1>Foobar!</h1>{% endblock %}
```

Which files I need to include in base.html ......?

Comment: templates need to be in script tags with ID's . Text for a title tag doesn't need a template, it's just text. You haven't explained any relationship between extend.html and base.html.

Comment: express-hbs supporting it

Answer (score 3):

Handlebars does not provide template inheritance out-of-the-box.

However, there are libraries that provide the helpers necessary to do template inheritance. My favorite is [Wax On](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wax-on) because it is based on the template inheritance in Pug and Django and works as you expect.

There is also [handlebars-layouts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars-layouts) which works a little differently, but it can also run client-side, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to extend partials to support 'blocks', see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Wilfred/715ae4e22642cfff1dbd).

Answer (score 0):

```
// in my node server: using express and hbs 
hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/built/development/templates');
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('_base', {
    "STATIC_URL": app.get('STATIC_URL')
  });
});

// This is in my base template 
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# blog: http://ogp.me/ns/blog#">
    {{> _config_logged_out }}
    {{> _scripts }}
</head>
```